# C++ template type which has a specific member method

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, enable-if, c++-concepts

What is a good way to call a member function of template type? Will the below `foo()` code only compile for types that have the `bla()` function defined?

```
class A { void bla(); };

template<typename T>
void foo() {
    T t;
    t.bla();
}

int main() {
    foo<A>();
    return 0;
}
```

Can I use `boost::enable_if` to only define this function for types that have a `bla()` method? If yes, is that even a good idea? I imagine the idea of "concepts" (which I know nothing about) is possibly what needs to be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every type you try to invoke the foo function with, the compiler will generate a new foo function with the given it and compile, if you can compile the foo function with a given type, it will works.

So in your case, the foo function will work with every type that have a bla function and that have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample looks correct; it will error if instantiated on a type which does not have a `bla()` member, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It will also only compile for types which are default-constructible. The compiler will throw an error for any type which is not default constructible and does not have a `bla()` function that can accept no arguments.